Complex Transpose / Reformatting of Excel/CSV file - probably need VBA
I have a set of data (from a questionnaire) in which each questionnaire is on it's own row and each field is in a separate column. A simplified version is below:

It needs to be modified to this:

The first four columns are repeated and the field type and question value need to be on the on their own separate line.
Does anybody have any ideas on how to begin working on this? I'm stumped. I have basic powerquery skills and willing to learn VBA if it can do this. Is there another tool, besides Excel, that would be better suited for this? Thx.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"QID", "Date", "CID", "Email"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.


Using MS365 --> Dynamic Array Formulas, you could also try:
=LET(
     α, Table1[#All],
     δ, DROP(TAKE(α,,4),1),
     ε, DROP(TAKE(α,1),,4),
     φ, DROP(α,1,4),
     Θ, SEQUENCE(ROWS(φ)),
     Σ, HSTACK(
        CHOOSEROWS(δ,TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(φ)),Θ))),
        TOCOL(IF(Θ,ε)),
        TOCOL(φ)),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(TAKE(α,1,4),"Field Type","Values"),Σ))



thx. I'll be looking at this tomorrow.
